Typescript error showing in npm run build
I am new in next js. My problem is that when i am running npm run build, it is showing typescript error even though i am not using it in my project. I am implementation for internationalization and it works well. But npm run build command is showing ts error.
Layout.jsx
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar/page";
import SettingFloatButton from "./Button/SettingFloatButton";
import Navbar from "./Navbar/page";
const Layout = ({ children, lang }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="relative flex min-h-screen bg-gray-50 divide-x">
        <div className="min-h-full hidden bg-white xl:block lg:block md:block">
          <Sidebar lang={lang} />
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col flex-1">
          <Navbar lang={lang} />
          <div className="p-5 xl:p-10">
            <main>{children}</main>
            <SettingFloatButton lang={lang} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Layout;


my folder structure

error image

Even though i changed this file to tsx, that does not work
Error Text

Type error: Type 'OmitWithTag<{ children: any; lang: any; }, keyof LayoutProps, "default">' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [x: string]: never; }'.
Property 'lang' is incompatible with index signature.
Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.


Please add errors/text in general as text rather than images, this makes it easier to search for and helps visually impaired users.

It's telling you that layouts in Next.js do not accept extra props. See https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/layout#props

I used context to solve as like the below. If there any suggestion to improve please let me know.
LangContext
"use client";
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

const LocaleContext = createContext();

export const LocaleProvider = ({ locale, children }) => {
  const [currentLocale, setCurrentLocale] = useState(locale);

  return (
    <LocaleContext.Provider value={{ currentLocale, setCurrentLocale }}>
      {children}
    </LocaleContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useLocale = () => {
  return useContext(LocaleContext);
};

Layout.jsx
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="relative flex min-h-screen bg-gray-50 divide-x">
        <div className="min-h-full hidden bg-white xl:block lg:block md:block">
          <Sidebar />
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col flex-1">
          <Navbar />
          <div className="p-5 xl:p-10">
            <main>{children}</main>
            <SettingFloatButton />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Layout;

RootLayout.jsx
export default async function RootLayout({ children, params: { locale } }) {
  const messages = await getMessages();

  return (
    <html lang={locale}>
      {/* TODO:remove suppressHydrationWarning={true} */}
      <NextIntlClientProvider messages={messages}>
        <body suppressHydrationWarning={false} className={inter.className}>
          <LocaleProvider locale={locale}>
            <TanStackProvider>
              <div>{children}</div>
            </TanStackProvider>
          </LocaleProvider>
          <Toaster position="top-right" reverseOrder={false} />
        </body>
      </NextIntlClientProvider>
    </html>
  );
}

